# How to copy Angular / Node.js app to an other computer

Tags: node.js, angular, copy

Hi i want to move my project to a new computer.

I have installed node.js and mongoDB on my new computer

For the Angular app I know that I have to copy the frontEnd directory, remove node_modules directory and run npm install

But does it work the same way for the backend ? Or i have to reinstall mongoose, nodemon, express and all my stuff by hand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy entirely Angular project with all node_modules, and same for backend and it should work.

But I think it's not the right way to work with code project.
In my opinion you need to create repository for example in GitHub and to clone your project using the tool Git. And then no matter how many new computer you buy, you simply execute the commands:

```
git clone ---my-project---
npm i
```

That's all.

Comment: Thank you, if I use the git solution, i have to put node_modules in my git ignore ?

Comment: Yes, you need to put it inside gitignore. By the way when you create a new Angular project, you will see that automatically generated a gitignore file which already ignore many files and directories and node_modules are part of them.

Comment: Ok, since i have two distinct directory : backend and frontend, i have to run npm i on both right ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry about it. 
It works like an angular project.
This is because it was recorded in the package.json file when installing the package for the backend. 
So if you copy except node_module directory and run "npm i" it works perfectly.